# Uncaught ReferenceError when organizing components in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I got “Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" when I tried to organize my components. I’m currently trying to build a template for a website using React.

This is my script.js:

```
import HeaderElem from "./component/HeaderElem.js"


const BodyElem = function() {
  return (
    <div className='BodyElem'>
      <h1 className='BodyElem__h1'>I want to join the cool kids</h1>
        <ol className='BodyElem__ol'>
          <li>I want to join the cool kids</li>
          <li>I want to join the cool kids</li>
          <li>I want to join the cool kids</li>
          <li>I want to join the cool kids</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
  )
}


const FooterElem = function() {
  return (
    <footer className='FooterElem'>
          <small>placeholder text for footer</small>
    </footer>
  )
}


const Container = function() {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <HeaderElem/>
      <BodyElem/>  
      <FooterElem/>
    </div>
  )
}

const root = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<Container/>, root)
```

This is my HeaderElem:

```
const HeaderElemNav = function() {
  return (
    <ul className='HeaderElemNav__ul'>
      <li><a href='#'>Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  )
}


const HeaderElem = function() {
    return (
        <header className='HeaderElem'>
        <nav className='HeaderElem__nav'>
            <img class='HeaderElem__logo' src='./public/logo.jpg' alt='react logo'></img>
            <HeaderElemNav/>
        </nav>
        </header>
    )
}

export default HeaderElem;
```

This is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My awesome page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="root" id="root">

    </div>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/babel"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is what my file and folder looks like:
[image: folder capture]

this is in console where it says Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined. I'm using both Edge and Firefox browser and both says the same error.
[image: console capture]

Here is the full console:
[full console capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJgWO.png)

I expect the HeaderElem.js to be imported to the script.js. I separate the HeaderElem.js to a subfolder to be called in the script.

Comment: odd, your code uses `import`, and `require` isn't at all present in the code - perhaps the error is in one of the libraries you're loading

Comment: Add to the question how you are bundling your React code. Looks like babel (which is where your issue is).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error and stack trace

Comment: op here. I think i got the full error, I have attached the full screen capture in the post but I'm not sure about the stack trace.